# How to use NetworkBoundResource with suspend fun in Retorfit

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Retrofit, LiveData, Room (Android AAC). `NetworkBoundResource` is a great helper to combine network source and room provided by [googlesimple](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt).

Since Retrofit 2.6.0 introduced built-in support for suspend, I tried to modify `NetworkBoundResource` to use suspend funciton instaed of `LiveDataCallAdapter` but  encountered a lot of troubles.

Here's my modification:

```
abstract class NetworkBondResource<ResultType, RequestType>
@MainThread constructor() {
    private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>()

    private val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()

    init {
        result.value = Resource.loading(null)
    }

    fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<Resource<ResultType>>

    suspend fun load() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val dbSource = loadFromDb()
            result.addSource(dbSource) { data ->
                result.removeSource(dbSource)
                if (shouldFetch(data)) {
                    // ! HERE--------------
                    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        fetchFromNetwork(dbSource)
                    }
                } else {
                    result.addSource(dbSource) { newData ->
                        setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // others code...
}
```

The question is code within `result.addSource(dbSource)` unable to inherit external scope. I have to use `GlobalScope` to launch a new coroutine which will causing a 'Coroutine Leak' since it is not controlled by the `viewModel` scope.

Also I found [another way](https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/ArchApp/blob/master/data/repository/src/main/java/io/philippeboisney/repository/utils/NetworkBoundResource.kt). But this scheme violates the principle of a [single trusted source](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/docs/guide#truth), lost the core role of `NetworkBoundResource`.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: i'm in the same situation and i'm searching a solution, maybe you can try to look at this [link](https://medium.com/ideas-by-idean/android-adventure-512bbd78b05f)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, my solution was this. I recommend that you do not use GlobalScope [for these reasons](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc). Make it clear that result.addSoruce can only be declared within the main thread. I hope it helps you, if there is a better solution please let me know.

```
 private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<ResultType>>()
private val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()

suspend fun load(): NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType> {

    val context = Dispatchers.IO
    context + supervisorJob


    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            result.value = Resource.loading(null)
            val dbResult = loadFromDb()
            result.addSource(dbResult){data->
                result.removeSource(dbResult)
                if (shouldFetch(data)){
                   try {
                       CoroutineScope(context).launch {
                           fetchFromNetwork(dbResult)
                       }
                   }catch (e:Exception){
                       Timber.i("NetworkBoundResource: An error happened: $e")
                       result.addSource(dbResult){newData->
                           setValue(Resource.error(e.message!!, newData))
                       }
                   }
                }else{
                    Timber.i("NetworkBoundResource: Return data from local database")
                    result.addSource(dbResult){newData->
                        setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                    }

                }
            }

    }

    return this

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add coroutine functionality to NetworkBoundResource itself.

you can call coroutines when you override the functions , like this :

```
fun getList(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
): LiveData<Resource<List<Content>>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Content>, List<Content>>(coroutineScope) {
        override fun onFetchFailed() {
            super.onFetchFailed()
        }

        override fun saveCallResult(items: List<Content>) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                contentDao.addList(items)
            }
        }

        override fun shouldFetch(data: List<Content>?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<List<Content>> {
                contentDao.loadSportContents(sport)
        }

        override fun createCall(): LiveData<Resource<List<Content>>> {
            return pullSportContentFromServer(coroutineScope)
        }
    }.asLiveData()
}
```